# Duvida da Utilização do BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Meu código abaixo é para pegar o gênero dos filmes do site IMDB, porém eu não estou sabendo pegar a tag em especifico de gêneros do site, pois as vezes em vez dele pegar o gênero ele pega a tag de keywords, pois ele pega o primeiro `div` que ele acha.

```
def get_genero(soup):
genero = soup.find  ('div', attrs={'class':'see-more inline canwrap'})
print(genero)
if genero != None:
    return [a.text for a in genero.findAll('a')]
else:
    return None
```

Sendo que preciso pegar apenas os gêneros dos filmes do site IMDB. Queria saber como faço pra pegar um lugar especifico, usando o BeautifulSoup.

Link de um exemplo de pagina de um filme:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4575576/?ref_=adv_li_tt

Comment: Forneça o link da página que você está fazendo *scrapping*.

Comment: o link seria das paginas dos filmes https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4575576/?ref_=adv_li_tt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no seletor que você está buscando, existem vários `<div>` com essas três classes juntas em toda a página. O ideal é tentar criar um seletor que seja o mais específico possível do que você está tentando obter (alguns navegadores fornecessem o recurso de "*copiar seletor*" ou "*copiar xpath*", para um elemento específico quando visualizado no "inspecionar elemento").

Visualizando a estrutura da página, dá pra ver que os gêneros estão dentro do quarto `<div>` dentro do elemento com `id='titleStoryLine'`. Então pode utilizar o mesmo esquema de seletores css para obter o elemento:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4575576/?ref_=adv_li_tt').text)

genres = soup.select('#titleStoryLine div:nth-of-type(4) a')

for genre in genres:
   print(genre.text)
```

Resultando em:

```
Animation
Adventure
Comedy
Drama
Family
Fantasy
```

Comment: Boa Tarde, desse jeito apareceu None como resultado

Comment: Eu tinha utilizado a função `find` ao invés de `select`, corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das soluções que acabei encontrando foi pegar a div inteira da history line, e depois achar/selecionar um href que contenha aquela parte de palavras, da seguinte forma:

```
def get_genero(soup):
genero = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'titleStoryLine'})
genero = genero.select("a[href*=/search/title?genres]")
if genero != None:
    return [a.text for a in genero]
else:
    return None
```